# Listing events that only belong to a group

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, groups

I have CiviCRM 5.12 on drupal 7. I want to create a drupal view containing the next events that are printed if only the contact belongs to an authorized group. That is, when I create an event, I link it to a group with a custom field and in the view, I want to filter the events and keep those reserved for the group containing the contact corresponding to the user drupal.  Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can filter the views using CONTEXTUAL FILTERS. Add group custom field in CONTEXTUAL FILTERS set default value to use below php code

```
    civicrm_initialize();
    try {
      $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', [
        'return' => ["groups"],
        'id' => "user_contact_id",
      ]);
      return $result['group'];
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      return 0;
    }
```

[image]

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: it seems to work. But I've no results. How you reference groups to event custom field?

Comment: I guess you may need to figure out the return statement if logged in user in subscribed to more than 1 group .

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I miss some thing.  Logged in user can be in more than 1 group and, I want to show all events. I think I'm wrong when I link the costum field to the group.